# Composition of elements in dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

I've come across the following example:
$$ρ^3·σρ^2 = ρ^2σρ^{−1}ρ^2 = ρ^2σρ = ρσρ^{-1}ρ = ρσ = σρ^{−1} = σρ^5$$

And was wondering if it is true in general that $ρ^i·σρ^j = σρ^{i+j}$?

I know that $ρσ = σρ^{n-1}$ for the dihedral group $D_n$ so maybe that would help some how?

Comment: That's not even true in the example you've given!

Comment: Ahhh sorry just fixed it! @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Please fix some $n$, some dihedral group $D_n$, best give its order to eliminate conventions, and state an equality with some other letters, avoid $n$...

Comment: Sorry just fixed! @dan_fulea

Comment: From $rs = sr^{-1}$ in some group we have immediately $r^{-1}s = sr$ and thus $$r^i s r^j = r^i\ r^{-1}sr^{j-1}=\dots=r^i\ r^{-j}s$$ and same $$r^i s r^j =sr^{-i}\ r^j\ .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but what is true in general is $\rho^m \sigma \rho^k = \sigma \rho^{k-m}$.

This happens to correspond to $\rho^{k+m}$ in your specific example because (it appears you are working in $D_6$) $\rho^3=\rho^{-3}$.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!